# Non-local destructuring assignment in ES6

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-6

`var { foo: bar } = { foo: 123 };` works.

`{ foo: bar } = { foo: 123 };` does not.

How to make latter work, when `bar` is global variable, but destructuring happens inside function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the "Syntax Gotcha" section in the [understandinges6 book](https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read#leanpub-auto-destructuring-assignment), you will need to wrap it using parentheses because otherwise it will generate a syntax error. The opening curly brace is normally the beginning of a block, and blocks cannot be part of an assignment expression.

This [worked](http://www.es6fiddle.net/i6tujihq/) for me:

```
var bar;
({ foo: bar } = { foo: 123 });
console.log(bar); // 123
```

I've also tried:

```
var bar;
({ foo: bar }) = { foo: 123 };
console.log(bar); // ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment at eval
```

But the latter isn't working for me in es6lint, though the book says it is supposed to work.